# How to get the ActionBar height?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to get the height of the `ActionBar` (using Sherlock) every time an activity is created (specially to handle configuration changes on rotation where the ActionBar height might change).

For this I use the method `ActionBar.getHeight()` which works only when the `ActionBar` is shown.

When the first activity is created for the first time, I can call `getHeight()` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` callback. But this method is not called after.

So my question is when can I call getHeight() and be assured that it doesn't return 0?
Or if it is not possible, how can I set the height of the ActionBar ?

Answer (score 457, accepted):

While @birdy's answer is an option if you want to explicitly control the ActionBar size, there is a way to pull it up without locking the size that I found in support documentation.  It's a little awkward but it's worked for me.  You'll need a context, this example would be valid in an Activity.

```
// Calculate ActionBar height
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
{
    int actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

**Kotlin**:

```kotlin
val tv = TypedValue()
if (requireActivity().theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
    val actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, resources.displayMetrics)
}
```

Comment: great help !! but from where you find all such things !!

Comment: Generally from exhaustive Googling or drudging thru the developer handbook.  I think the latter in this case, but it's been a while.

Comment: Can we change the actionbar size only for a particular activity?

Comment: This worked for me in both cases: (i) onCreateView and (ii) onConfigurationChanged. Thanks!

Comment: I had to call getContext().getTheme()... instead of simply getTheme()

Comment: Hence why I said you need a 'context'. I suggest taking a look at the developer handbook to understand why.

Comment: As @muzikant mentioned below, for appcompat, you want to use `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize`. Works fine everywhere.

Comment: There's a reason for why it's so unwieldy if you think about each part in terms of abstract theme attributes and arbitrary device specs.

But if you think this is hard, try disambiguating "external storage" files in 4.2+.  They're *mounted* not *linked* in three locations.  

Then when you're done with that if you're on 4.4+ you can suffer the "rich" (google for atrocious) Document API to write to external SD cards.

Comment: android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize works perfectly for me

Comment: "android.R.attr.actionBarSize" is not working in android version 2.3, but "R.attr.actionBarSize" is working android all version. just use "R.attr.actionBarSize" instead of "android.R.attr.actionBarSize", "android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize" and etc.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the updates guys.  The support library is a far cry from what it was when this was posted.  Using the support attr is definitely the way to go if you support pre-AB Android.

Comment: Only `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize` worked with me on galaxy s3 and everywhere.

Comment: Is it possible to get an explanation of what was done. And possibly also how you could do it in javafx?

Comment: We get some number, but it's definitely not the same as the action bar height.

Comment: `androidx.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize` for androidx

Comment: Also notice that the result value is in pixels, so if you want 'dp', you must convert the value using `(int) Math.ceil(pixel / density)` to dp.
For example I needed this conversion to pass the result to LayoutParams height.

Answer (score 159):

In XML, you should use this attribute:

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: I think he means: `"?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: in case you are using ActionBarCompat "@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height"

Comment: Thanks Ali AlNoaimi! With AppCompat v21 the name has changed to: "@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"

Comment: As @muzikant mentioned below, for appcompat, if you want to use it in the code, the correct attribute is `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize`. If you want to use it in layout xml, `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`. Works fine everywhere.

Comment: This solution is wonderful when you are using a custom XML framelayout.

Comment: If I want to use this attr but negative to use it with a negative padding. How can I do that?

Comment: It gives exact size of ActionBar. More useful. Thanks.

Comment: if I add a view programatically to the actionBarSize the height will be updated ?

Comment: It depends if you invalidate the changes so the layout can re-calculate its size again.

Comment: Great solution when using ConstraintLayout

Comment: @cesards , how to do this using java?

Answer (score 18):

Ok I was googling around and get to this post several times so I think it'll be good to be described not only for Sherlock but for appcompat also:

**Action Bar height using appCompat**

Pretty similiar to @Anthony description you could find it with following code(I've just changed resource id):

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();

if (getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
{
    int actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

**Pre Sandwitch Problem**

I needed action bar height because on pre ICE_CREAM_SANDWITCH devices my view was overlaping action bar. I tried setting android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize", android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize", setting overlap off to view/actionbar and even fixed actionbar height with custom theme but nothing worked. That's how it looked:

[image: overlap problem]

Unfortunately I found out that with method described above I get only half of the height(I assume that options bar is not taken in place) so to completely fix the isue I need to **double** action bar height and everything seems ok:

[image: overlap fixed]

If someone knows better solution(than doubling actionBarHeight) I'll be glad to let me know as I come from iOS development and I found most of Android view's stuff pretty confusing :)

Regards,

hris.to

Comment: I experienced the same thing when using tabs. Problem is it's sometimes hard to detect tabs vs. no tabs, since some devices visually collapse the tabs into the base ActionBar in some situations. So what worked for me is just `ActionBar.getHeight()`. Depending on the situation, that may work for you too.

Comment: I was facing the issue cuz I was only considering actionbar's height, then I added 'notification bar's' height as well. It worked well for me.

Comment: Do you use FrameLayout and have `layout_gravity="center_vertical"`? Change it to `"bottom"`. Android 2.3 handles margin in FrameLaoyut differently than newer androids.

Answer (score 16):

@Anthony answer works for devices that support `ActionBar` and for those devices which support only `Sherlock Action Bar` following method must be used

```
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    if(actionBarHeight ==0 && getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.actionbarsherlock.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)){
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

   //OR as stated by @Marina.Eariel
   TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
      if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
   }else if(getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.actionbarsherlock.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true){
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
   }
```

Comment: You could wrap the first if with "if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {}" to avoid runtime errors on older Android versions.

Comment: For me `com.actionbarsherlock.R.attr.actionBarSize` worked for both Android 2.3 and 4.0, so it looks like you can use this regardless of the Android version.

Answer (score 14):

i think the safest way would be :

```
private int getActionBarHeight() {
    int actionBarHeight = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
    if (actionBarHeight != 0)
        return actionBarHeight;
    final TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } else if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.actionbarsherlock.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    return actionBarHeight;
}
```

Comment: in case you are using appcompat, add the following: `else if (true == getTheme().resolveAttribute(
    android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
  {
   actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
     tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  }`

Comment: "if (true== " ? I think you can remove the "true"... :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right... that's just added for clarity

Comment: From your code it looks like it doesnt matter if im using ABS, in all versions above HONEYCOMB it will take the actionbar height from android.R.attr.actionBarSize. Is this correct ?

Comment: is it anyway to specify the half action bar to hide top of the screen?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163374/hide-only-the-action-bar-on-scroll-not-action-bar-tabs

Answer (score 7):

To set the height of `ActionBar` you can create new `Theme` like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
    <style name="Theme.FixedSize" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item> 
    </style> 
 </resources>
```

and set this `Theme` to your `Activity`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.FixedSize"
```

Comment: Do notice that the height of the action bar is smaller in landscape mode.

Comment: I don't recommend this since actionBarSherlock takes a lot into account when deciding the actionbar height. If you do this the actionBar height won't be based on device specs and hence won't look like the standard height for certain devices.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a Toolbar as the ActionBar,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

then just use the layout_height of the toolbar.

```
int actionBarHeight = toolbar.getLayoutParams().height;
```

Answer (score 5):

Java:

```
    int actionBarHeight;
    int[] abSzAttr;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        abSzAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize };
    } else {
        abSzAttr = new int[] { R.attr.actionBarSize };
    }
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(abSzAttr);
    actionBarHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, -1);
```

xml:

```
    ?attr/actionBarSize
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an updated version with Kotlin I used assuming phone is higher than Honeycomb:

```
val actionBarHeight = with(TypedValue().also {context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, it, true)}) {
            TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(this.data, resources.displayMetrics)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Xamarin/C#, this is the code you're looking for:

```
var styledAttributes = Context.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(new[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ActionBarSize });
var actionBarSize = (int)styledAttributes.GetDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.Recycle();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this function to get actionbar's height.

```
public int getActionBarHeight() {
    final TypedArray ta = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[] {android.R.attr.actionBarSize});
    int actionBarHeight = (int) ta.getDimension(0, 0);
    return actionBarHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A ready method to fulfill the most popular answer:

```
public static int getActionBarHeight(
  Activity activity) {

  int actionBarHeight = 0;
  TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

  try {

    if (activity
      .getTheme()
      .resolveAttribute(
        android.R.attr.actionBarSize,
        typedValue,
        true)) {

      actionBarHeight =
        TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
          typedValue.data,
          activity
            .getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics());
    }

  } catch (Exception ignore) {
  }

  return actionBarHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This helper method should come in handy for someone. Example: `int actionBarSize = getThemeAttributeDimensionSize(this, android.R.attr.actionBarSize);`

```
public static int getThemeAttributeDimensionSize(Context context, int attr)
{
    TypedArray a = null;
    try{
        a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { attr });
        return a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
    }finally{
        if(a != null){
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you just have to add this.

```
public int getActionBarHeight() {
        int height;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            height = getActivity().getActionBar().getHeight();
        } else {
            height = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getHeight();

        }
        return height;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a more generic way to discover it:

```
  int[] location = new int[2];
  mainView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
  int toolbarHeight = location[1];
```

where '**mainView**' is the root view of your layout.

The idea is basically get the Y position of the **mainView** as it is set right below the ActionBar (or Toolbar).

Answer (score 2):

The action bar height differs according to the applied theme.
If you're using **AppCompatActivity** the height will be different in most of cases from the normal Activity.

If you're using **AppCompatActivity** you should use R.attr.actionBarSize instead of android.R.attr.actionBarSize

```
public static int getActionBarHeight(Activity activity) {
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

        int attributeResourceId = android.R.attr.actionBarSize;
        if (activity instanceof AppCompatActivity) {
            attributeResourceId = R.attr.actionBarSize;
        }

        if (activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attributeResourceId, typedValue, true)) {
            return TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typedValue.data, activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        return (int) Math.floor(activity.getResources()
                .getDimension(R.dimen.my_default_value));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In xml, you can use ?attr/actionBarSize, but if you need access to that value in Java you need to use below code:

```
public int getActionBarHeight() {
        int actionBarHeight = 0;
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv,
                    true))
                actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                        tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        } else {
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,
                    getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return actionBarHeight;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The action bar now enhanced to app bar.So you have to add conditional check for getting height of action bar.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   height = getActivity().getActionBar().getHeight();
 } else {
  height = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to find actionbar height is from Activity `onPrepareOptionMenu` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           ....
           int actionBarHeight = getActionBar().getHeight());
           .....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In javafx (using Gluon), the height is set at runtime or something like it. While being able to get the width just like normal...

`double width = appBar.getWidth();`

You have to create a listener:

`GluonApplication application = this;`

```
application.getAppBar().heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        // Take most recent value given here
        application.getAppBar.heightProperty.get()
    }
});
```

...And take the most recent value it changed to. To get the height.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything that's out there without success, I found out, by accident, a functional and very easy way to get the action bar's default height.

Only tested in API 25 and 24

C#

```
Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Dimension.abc_action_bar_default_height_material);
```

Java

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height_material);
```