# Actionbarsherlock getHeight() returns 0

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Actionbarsherlock and I want to place a `PopupWindow` right below the action bar. Using the `showAtLocation()` takes an x and y offset, so ideally the y offset would be the height of the action bar. But when I call

```
int abHeight = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
```

it returns zero. I'm using a `SherlockFragmentActivity`

Here's the relevant code:

```
slidingLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu, null);
menuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT, Position.LEFT);
menuDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
menuDrawer.setMenuView(slidingLayout.findViewById(R.id.sliding_menu));

getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
int abHeight = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
```

I've looked all over and can't find a similar question/answer, so has anyone experienced this before? Thanks.

EDIT: Jake's answer was right on. In order to get that attribute value I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13216807/1754999).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the height of the action bar from the `actionBarSize` theme attribute. This changes based on the device configuration so make sure you are always reading it when your activity is created or recreated.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I used http://stackoverflow.com/a/13216807/1754999 to get the size and it all worked. I think there might be a dp to px issue in there somewhere but I'll get that figured out.

Answer (score 2):

in you style.XML  add:   `<item name="@android:attr/actionBarSize">50px</item>`

and then in your activity add the following code :

```
 TypedArray actionbarSizeTypedArray = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {  android.R.attr.actionBarSize});  

        int h = (int) actionbarSizeTypedArray.getDimension(0, 0);
```

this is one kind ,I am trying to get other ways.Good luck!

Yeah!I find a way very simple:

```
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
    {
        int  h=TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

more info,look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the height for views until they have been layed out.  Try adding a `ViewTreeObserver`:

```
someView.getViewTreeObserver().addGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Remember to remove it if you don't want it to fire every time
        someView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        int abHeight = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
        // Use the height as desired...
    }
});
```

Refer to the docs starting at [`View.getViewTreeObserver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getViewTreeObserver%28%29).