# Android actionbarsherlock get height return 0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, height, actionbarsherlock

I was looking for get the height of my actionbar(sherlock). The value returned is 0.

value/styles.xml  (and for value11 I used "android:actionBarSize")

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
</style>
```

code :

```
getSupportActionBar().getHeight()
```

Comment: Where are you calling this `getSupportActionBar().getHeight()`?

Comment: @puj after setContentView()

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192133/actionbarsherlock-getheight-returns-0

Comment: @puj I already saw, I did the same thing but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't work?

```
// Calculate ActionBar height
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
{
    actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

ref: [How to get the ActionBar height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height/13216807#13216807)

Comment: Have you tried after your view has been layed out?  For instance, in `onResume`?