# Error when getting a dimension in theme for margins

Tags: android, android-theme, margins, dimension

### Background

I'm trying to set a custom margin value on the listView items based on the selected theme.

The app has multiple themes, and the user can choose which theme to use , which I set by calling "setTheme()" .

### The problem

whatever I try, I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
```

note that this occurs only for the margin attribute, and so far no other attribute has caused this.

### What I've tried

first, here's the xml snippets I've used

attrs.xml

```
<attr name="listview_item__horizontal_spacing" format="dimension" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme_HoloDark" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
  <item name="listview_item__horizontal_spacing">4dp</item>
  ....
```

the layout of the listView item:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
    android:layout_marginLeft="?attr/listview_item__horizontal_spacing" >
```

I've also tried using "reference" for the attribute type, and reference to a "dimen" resource, but it also cause the same exception.

Another thing I've tried is getting it dynamically:

```
public static int getResIdFromAttribute(final Activity activity,final int attr)
    {
    final TypedValue typedvalueattr=new TypedValue();
    activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr,typedvalueattr,true);
    return typedvalueattr.resourceId;
    }

...
final int spacingResId=getResIdFromAttribute(activity,R.attr.listview_item__horizontal_spacing);
```

but for some reason I get 0 as the result of this call. Only when using [**this method**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13216807/878126) it worked.

### The question

What is going on? How can I avoid this?

Is there really no way to overcome this but using code (when inflating the xml) ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use *attr* XML, and this is your issue.

Place your the value you want in a file named dimens.xml in your res folder (same location as strings.xml).

This file will look something like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="value1">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="value2">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then in your layout XML, you can reference the dimen directly (just as you would reference a string), something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value1" >
```

or when defining a style, in your XML it would look like:

```
 <style name="MyStyle1">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/value1</item>
    </style>
```

and then for your other style:

```
<style name="MyStyle2">
            <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/value2</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: I want to set the dimension based on the current theme (which the user can choose, and then I use "setTheme()" before the activity is really created. What you've offered here is completely static.

Comment: You will need to just create the logic to make these changes.  You would put a different dimen value each of your styles (ie. a different value entirely for each style, that has it's own unique value in the dimen folder).

Comment: Added solution to answer.

Comment: What you've written is still very static. I need to support : setTheme(R.style.MyTheme1) and setTheme(R.style.MyTheme2) , each will have the dimension of the margin to a different value.

Comment: When you change between MyTheme1 and MyTheme2, the dimen will change from Value1 to Value2 - this is exactly what my answer shows, and is the correct way to do this.

Comment: You didn't write a theme that changes the margin. you've written about themes that change the text size. the margin attribute in what you've written will always point to "@dimen/value1" , no matter which theme is used.

Comment: I changed that (thought you might figure out they concept).  This example is now accurate.

Comment: What you've written will change the margin for all views, and I wish to do it for a specific ones that use the attribute I've set. What I want is : set the theme for the entire activity, and each attribute that is used on a view will match according to what the theme specifies. The current attribute I've asked about is used for specific views, on their margins.