# Android Action Bar Height returns 0 even though action bar is visible

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm having an issue where no matter what I try `getActionBar().getHeight()` always returns 0. the action bar is clearly visible , so I don't know what might be causing the issue.

```
System.out.println(lP.height + " + " + getActionBar().getHeight());
lP.height = lP.height + getActionBar().getHeight();
System.out.println(lP.height);
```

there really isn't much code to show. the output looks like:

```
900 + 0
900
```

I have all of the app wrapped in a `FrameLayout`, including the action bar, so that I can place items on top of it, but I know I can still get the right action bar reference using `getActionBar()` because I can see the background changing when I use `getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable)`. just for some reason `getHeight()` always returns 0.

Comment: where do you make the call?

Comment: `onCreate()`. Let me try in other places too to see if it's that.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height

Comment: hmm it seems to work when called from an `OnScrollChangedListener` so it probably has to do with the order in which the view is created. This means I need to call it after onCreate(), because that is the last call in `onCreate()`, so it means the ActionBar is created after the activity is created

Comment: @Sophicles your answer works, thank you very much. I started looking for an `onDraw` or something similar but this is much nicer. If you want you can write it as a top level answer so I can approve it.

Comment: See the quesiton here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height

Comment: height is not yet calculated in **onCreate** method. So, if you try your code in **onResume** then I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

using this Listener [GlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r)

This Listener will be called when its Attached to the Layout with the Correct width and height

just dont forget to remove the listener after your get variables

Comment: this works great but I prefer @Sophicles' answer, so I'll use that one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it working!