# Android navigation bar size in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Is there any way to get the size of navigation bar in android in xml file similar to this?

```
 android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

where actionBarSize is navigation bar size?

Comment: you mean "`ActionBar`" by "nagivation bar"? If you need to get the `ActionBar`'s height, refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height

Comment: No, I mean navigation bar (the one which is diplayed on devices without hardware buttons).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After looking in android source it looks like there is dimens for navigation bar height :

```
@android:dimen/navigation_bar_height
```

[There](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml) are other dimens linked to nav bar, examples from android values/dimens.xml  :

```
<!-- Height of the bottom navigation / system bar. -->
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height">48dp</dimen>
<!-- Height of the bottom navigation bar in portrait; often the same as @dimen/navigation_bar_height -->
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height_landscape">48dp</dimen>
<!-- Width of the navigation bar when it is placed vertically on the screen -->
<dimen name="navigation_bar_width">42dp</dimen>
```

Comment: `Error:(167, 39) Resource is not public. (at 'layout_marginBottom' with value '@android:dimen/navigation_bar_height').`

Comment: @IonAalbers On which version of Android are you working ?

Comment: Same problem. Any solution?

Comment: Have the same issue. Can't customize a layout for non-navbar devices.

Comment: I had the same problem as Ion Aalbers. Using Max's solution worked for me, so I moved my padding and margins to `onCreate`.

Comment: Well, I just wrote the private property in my project's dimens. Is there any problem? Seems like it's 48dp for all devices anyway.

Comment: Hi Gaëtan,
I get this error when I add this code to my xml: "@android:dimen/navigation_bar_height"

Error: "resource android:dimen/navigation_bar_height is private"

Could you please help mp?

Comment: AAPT: error: resource android:dimen/navigation_bar_height is private.

Answer (score 8):

Try this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264268/how-to-get-height-and-width-of-navigation-bar-programmatically):

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: OP specifically requested in XML.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in many of similar questions, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29938139/9640177), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26118045/9640177), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50775459/9640177), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41057024/9640177), simply getting navigation bar height may not be enough. We need to consider whether *1. navigation bar exists, 2. is it on the bottom, or right or left, 3. is app open in multi-window mode.*

**There is a simple one line solution**

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

or programatically

```
findViewById(R.id.your_root_view).setFitsSystemWindows(true);
```

you may also get root view by

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
or
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

For more details on getting root-view refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488149/9640177