# Hide only the Action bar on Scroll not action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am getting an issue at trying to hide the action bar while scrolling down.Then while scrolling up,the action bar have to shown again.

**For Eg:**

I referred this [Tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-maximize-android-screen-real-estate-by-showing-and-hiding-the-action-bar/).Here you can see the output and respective codes related to hide and show the action bar.

I am showing the **output** what I get it till now.

[image]

**After scrolling down:**

[image]

The screenshot above shown, it hide the action bar tab also.But it have to hide only the action bar.That's the major issue.

**After scrolling up:**

[image]

The screenshot above shows it displays back the action bar with tabs.

**TopRatedFragment.java:**

```
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment implements ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener {

    private float mActionBarHeight;
    private ActionBar actionBar;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

        final TypedArray styledAttributes = getActivity().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
        mActionBarHeight = styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        styledAttributes.recycle(); 
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();  



        ((ScrollView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.parent)).getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

        float y = ((ScrollView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parent)).getScrollY();
        if (y >= mActionBarHeight && actionBar.isShowing()) {
            actionBar.hide();
        } else if ( y==0 && !actionBar.isShowing()) {
            actionBar.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_top_rated.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" 
            android:orientation="vertical" >  

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

               .
               .
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

My issue is, While scrolling down it only have to hide the action bar only not action bar tabs.

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView ? look at the top-right part of the gif animation...

Comment: @androiddeveloper post your comment as an answer with that specified gif image.It seems I need to work in gradle.If your solution works for me I will accept your answer and place a bounty.

Comment: ok, posted. hope it helps.

Comment: Actionbar tabs are deprecated.  You need to 1st migrate the actionbar tabs to a viewpager.

Answer (score 16):

I think [**this library**](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) and its sample could help you.

Look at the top-right gif animation:

[image: image.gif]

I think the sample file is called "[**ViewPagerTabScrollViewActivity**](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/observablescrollview-samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/ViewPagerTabScrollViewActivity.java)"

Comment: That was not working.Because there was no layout even in the single actiivty.

Comment: what output? I don't understand.

Comment: I talked to that Github publisher.I get a reply like this.`The sample app cannot be built without layout files.
I tried importing the project again, but unfortunately I couldn't see
those errors...

So... I have some questions.

1. What is your OS? (I'm using Mac OS X 10.10)

2. What commit are you trying to build? (Git commit hash, like
"36cd555" or something)

3. What is your Android Studio version? (I'm using or tested on 1.0 RC
1, RC 2 and RC 4.)`

Comment: `4. Does the command line build also fail?
    ("./gradlew assembleDebug" on Mac/Linux and "gradlew.bat
assembleDebug" on Windows.
     If the build succeeded, you can get the apk in
"observablescrollview-samples/build/outputs/apk/" directory.)

5. Does it happen only on this project?

6. Are the Android SDK location and JDK location properly set on
Default Project Structure setting?
    (File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure)`

Thank you,
Soichiro Kashima`

Comment: @Naruto Sorry, I still don't understand. Have you failed to launch his sample? Are those questions for me? If so, here are my answers:  1. I use Windows OS 8.1 .  2. Just used the normal one, nothing special. 3. I tried on both Android Studio and Eclipse, didn't check the version but I always try to keep them updated. 4. I never tried to use Gradle on the command line.I'm quite new to Gradle. 5. What happens? 6. Yes, it works fine for me.

Comment: He told me to use android studio exact version.But I didn't had that version.But I tried in android studio.Didn't worked for me.He told me it will achieve only in android studio.now time running out and I am shifted to some other project

Comment: @Naruto Sorry for the experience you had. If it makes you feel better or comfort you, I also had a lot of issues using Android Studio, and I still have from time to time. I still prefer Eclipse on many aspects, but maybe Android-Studio will become better over time that I will get used to it.

Comment: how do you implement the following

Comment: how to implement the following library?

Comment: You probably mean "how do you import the above library" , as it's already implemented, and you just need to import it. use Android Studio, and choose "VCS"->"checkout from version control"->github-> "https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView.git" .

Comment: No i mean how do you use the library.. Importing is not a big deal just use the compile link in the gradle file

Comment: I am looking for a tutorial to implement the "viewpagertabscrollactivity"

Comment: @virus You should ask on Github instead. Maybe it changed since last time I've tried, but it was quite easy at the time. I just launched it...