# ImageView Inside the ScrollView should fit device layout

Tags: java, android, layout, imageview, scrollview

Please help me in designing the screen as follows[image]

I want to set the imageview to device layout.
Ex: if i run the app in 5 inch screen, only image view should show up, i need to scroll down to see the description. similarly when i run the app in 4 inch screen, only image view should show up without any cut in image.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/category_scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dishDetailPageImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="565dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

//description contents

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Elltz i've updated my xml. for ImaveView i've set the height as 565dp. I want to apply autolayout that should adjust as per the screen size. If i give "match_parent" or "fill_parent" i'm not getting the proper output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the height of `ImageView` directly in layout XML file.

You need to find the height of your screen programmatically and then need to set `LayoutParams` to your `ImageView`.

Here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Get the height of device screen.
2. Get the height of `ActionBar`.
3. Get the height of `StatusBar`.

Height-For-`ImageView` = 1-2-3.

Here is the XML file that you can use.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_image"
            android:text="Hello how are you?, Hello how are you?, Hello how are you?,Hello how are you? ,Hello how are you? " />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is how you can set height programmatically in activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ImageView ivImage = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels/displayMetrics.density);
        int width = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels/displayMetrics.density);

        // Calculate ActionBar height
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        int actionBarHeight=0;
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        {
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(displayMetrics.widthPixels, (displayMetrics.heightPixels-actionBarHeight-getStatusBarHeight()));
        ivImage.setLayoutParams(param);
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Sources of Answer:

1. [Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)
2. [How to get the ActionBar height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height)

Let me know if it help.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically set the height of the ImageView By:

```
ImageView yourImageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthOfTheImage,getScreenSize(context)[1]));
```

Get the screen size:

```
public static int[] getScreenSize(Context context) 
{
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics=context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int screenWidthInPix = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    int screenheightInPix = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    return (new int[] {  screenWidthInPix,screenheightInPix });
}
```

Comment: This is a possible solution, but you must do this after the view has been measured, otherwise the measurement will override your orders.