# Action Bar height difference between the attr and runtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar

If I do this:

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = getBaseContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[]{R.attr.actionBarSize});
    mActionBarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
    styledAttributes.recycle();
```

**mActionBarHeight = 144**

If I do this:

```
mActionBarHeight = getSupportActionBar().getHeight() ;
```

**mActionBarHeight = 168**

Is there a way of obtaining the same value on the onCreate method of my Activity. If i ran the second option on the onCreate method I get 0, of course.

Comment: Take a look at the answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13216807/1399597).

Comment: Same result as my first option.