# Android:How to get the coordinate of a view(not include Actionbar)

Tags: android, view

Using `View.getLocationOnScreen()`can get the coordinate, but it is a little larger than I expected, so I think the coordinate I get is relative to the full screen (which including `ActionBar`) .
Is there any method can I get the coordinate without includig `ActionBar`?
See the picture below.

[image: I want the green 'y',not the yellow one]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the absolute coordinates of a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please first see this image:

[image]

This link show you how get the current position of button(110 in picture)

[How to get the absolute coordinates of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view)

The second link calculate the Actionbar height(72 in picture)

[How to get the ActionBar height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height)

And the last link show you how to calculate the Statusbar(38 in picture)

[Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)

And now you can get the current position with this equal(110 = 72 + 38)

Hope to help you.