# How to get the height of the action bar and the notification bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, touch-event

I want to set the coordinates of my button equal to the coordinates of the  point I touch on mobile. I am using the method `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`.

```
button.setY(event.getRawY() -  actionBarHeight - notificationBarHeight);
```

How can I get height of my **Action Bar** and **Notification Bar**.

Comment: you can find solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height

Answer (score 1):

You can get the height of your ActionBar with

```
getActionBar().getHeight();
```

It's said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android) (answer 3 and 4) that status bar is 25dp until Marshmallow, and 24dp since Marshmallow.

Comment: Please tell me the way to get height of notification bar too.

Comment: I don't really understand what is the notification bar, can you put a screenshot ?

Comment: Notification bar is the same as status bar, where time, battery, signals, etc are shown, which you drag down from the top to see the notifications of calls, messages and other.