# How to get Navigation bar Height in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android, navigationbar

how to get top navigation bar Height in Xamarin Android? below is the java code

```
public static int getSceenHeight(Activity activity) {
   //obsolete now
    return activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()+getNavigationBarHeight(activity);
}

 public static int getNavigationBarHeight(Activity activity) {
    if (!isNavigationBarShow(activity)){
        return 0;
    }
    Resources resources = activity.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height",
            "dimen", "android");
    int height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    return height;
}

public static boolean isNavigationBarShow(Activity activity){

        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        Point realSize = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        display.getRealSize(realSize);
        return realSize.y!=size.y;

    }
}
```

how to apply this in Xamarin Android ?

Comment: Top navigation bar or bottom navigation bar?

Comment: top one that displays signal, battery etc

Comment: FYI, the top space displaying battery, signal, notification & time called 'status bar'. That is always fixed & have height: 24dp.

Comment: ok it is navigation bar, i thought navigation bar is the one displays the battery,  i want navigation bar height then, i am converting from java, i will post the code in a min

Comment: You should say Toolbar/Actionbar. Height of toolbar is always for mobile device is 48dp

Comment: i posted the java code

Answer (score 3):

Seem like there is this forever ongoing confusion about what is called a NavigationBar when it comes to Xamarin/Xamarin.Form and Android. I really wish that Xamarin would fix this naming so that it is in line with android.

Anyway, Calling ...

```
int resourceId = resources.GetIdentifier("navigation_bar_height",
            "dimen", "android");
```

...is going to return the value for the bottom NavigationBar(Android)(the buttons that is part of the OS). From the comments above it seems like you are looking for the Xamarin NavigationBar(The Top one that contains menu Title and so on (Bellow status bar)).

Please try the following

```
var styledAttributes = Context.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(new[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ActionBarSize });
var actionBarSize = (int)styledAttributes.GetDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.Recycle();
```

Thanks to [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4795187/fred) for his post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29667687/3937464)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you gonna use it, as you said I have converted above you methods to C#

```
public static int getSceenHeight(Activity activity)
{
    //obsolete now
    return activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Height + getNavigationBarHeight(activity);
}

public static int getNavigationBarHeight(Activity activity)
{
    if (!isNavigationBarShow(activity))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    Resources resources = activity.Resources;
    int resourceId = resources.GetIdentifier("navigation_bar_height",
            "dimen", "android");
    int height = resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    return height;
}

public static bool isNavigationBarShow(Activity activity)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr1)
    {
        Display display = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
        Point size = new Point();
        Point realSize = new Point();
        display.GetSize(size);
        display.GetRealSize(realSize);
        return realSize.Y != size.Y;
    }
    else
    {
        bool menu = ViewConfiguration.Get(activity).HasPermanentMenuKey;
        bool back = KeyCharacterMap.DeviceHasKey(Keycode.Back);
        if (menu || back)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method to get status bar(top one that displays signal, battery etc as you said)

```
private int getStatusBarHeight()
{
    Resources res = this.Resources;
    int resourceId = res.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    int height = res.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    return height;
}

The method to get navigation bar
        private int getNavigationBarHeight()
{
            Resources res = this.Resources;
            int resourceId = res.GetIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            int height = res.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            return height;
}
```